# How differentiate the stereographic projection map

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{S^2} \setminus {(0,0,1)}\to\mathbb{R^2} $ be the stereographic projection of a sphere onto a plane.

Find the derivative of $f$.

Note: You should get a linear map from 2-d space to 2-d space

---

I'm new to the idea of differentiation of manifolds.

First I need two manifolds M and N and a smooth map between them

$M$ is the $\mathbb{S^2} \setminus {(0,0,1)} $ paramaterized as $\{(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$

$N$ is the equatorial plane $\{z=0\}$

Now I need a smooth map between the two manifolds $f:M\to N $ $\space where \space(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$
.

Now I need to associate each point $s\in M$ with a tangent space $TM_x$

This lets us define the derivative $df_x:TM_x\to TN_y$

According to my book (Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint)
we choose a parametrization where $U$ is a subset of ${R^m}$ and M is a subset of ${R^k}$.

$g:U\to M$ of a neighborhood g(U) of x in M, with g(u) = x and the derivative is
$dg_u: {R^m} \to {R^k}$

We have our parametrization of $M$, $\{(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$

$TM_x$ is the image of $dg_x \circ dg_u$

Now I am a little confused. I'd like a concrete example like this to work from where I can say,

This is my a manifold M, this is another manifold N, I have a smooth map between them, this is how I generate the tangent space, and this is how I calculate the derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $p:= (x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Then we can identify $T_{p} S^2\cong \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x,y,z)\perp (x_0,y_0,z_0) \}$ by the differential $d\iota$ of the inclusion $\iota: S^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. The map $F: \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{z = 1\} \to \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y,z)\mapsto \frac{(x,y)}{1-z}$ extends $f$. The differential at $p$ is
$$dF_{p}: \mathbb{R}^3\cong T_{p}(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{z = 1\}) \to \mathbb{R}^2\cong T_{F(p)}\mathbb{R}^2, \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right)(p)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1-z_0} & 0 & \frac{x_0}{(1-z_0)^2} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{1-z_0} & \frac{y_0}{(1-z_0)^2}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the differential of $f$ at $p$ is
$$df_{p}: T_{p} S^2\cong \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ (x,y,z)\perp (x_0,y_0,z_0) \} \to \mathbb{R}^2\cong T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}^2, \\ 
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1-z_0} & 0 & \frac{x_0}{(1-z_0)^2} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{1-z_0} & \frac{y_0}{(1-z_0)^2}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}$$

For example for $z_0 > 0$ we can choose the basis $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ -\frac{x_0}{z_0}\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\\ -\frac{y_0}{z_0}\end{pmatrix}$ coming from the parametrization $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$. Then the differential is given by
$$df_p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1-z_0} & 0 & \frac{x_0}{(1-z_0)^2} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{1-z_0} & \frac{y_0}{(1-z_0)^2}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ -\frac{x_0}{z_0} & -\frac{y_0}{z_0}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
\\ = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1-z_0}-\frac{x_0^2}{z_0(1-z_0)^2} & -\frac{x_0 y_0}{z_0(1-z_0)^2} \\ -\frac{x_0 y_0}{z_0(1-z_0)^2} & \frac{1}{1-z_0}-\frac{y_0^2}{z_0(1-z_0)^2} \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

The stereographic projection map is

$f:\mathbb{S^2} \setminus {(0,0,1)}\to\mathbb{R^2} $

$(x,y,z) \mapsto (\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z})$

When we try and find our Jacobian, we know we want a $2 \times2$ matrix, but we have three variable?

When we make our Jacobian, we want local coordinates

$x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \leftarrow \rightarrow z=\sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}$

so we can define our map as

$f:\mathbb{S^2} \setminus {(0,0,1)}\to\mathbb{R^2} $

$(x,y,z) \mapsto (\frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})$

which is in two variables

The Jacobian becomes

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{y}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{y}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Computing this, compute the determinant, and we are finished.